# How to pass a reference to a JS function as an argument to an ExternalInterface call?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, facebook, externalinterface

**Summary**
I want to be able to call a JavaScript function from a Flex app using ExternalInterface and pass a reference to a different JavaScript function as an argument.

**Base Example**
Given the following JavaScript:

```
function foo(callback)
{
    // ... do some stuff
    callback();
}

function bar()
{
    // do some stuff that should happen after a call to foo
}
```

I want to call `foo` from my flex app using ExternalInterface and pass a reference to `bar` as the callback.

**Why**
Really,`foo` is not my function (but, rather, `FB.Connect.showBookmarkDialog`), which due to restrictions on Facebook iframe apps can only be called on a button click.  My button, for design reasons, is in the Flex app.  Fortunately, it's possible to call `ExternalInterface.call("FB.Connect.showBookmarkDialog", callback)` to display the bookmark dialog. But, `FB.Connect.showBookmarkDialog` requires a JS callback so, should I want to receive a callback (which I do), I need to pass a reference to a JS function as the single argument.

**Real Example**

MXML:

```
<mx:Button click="showBookmarkDialog();" />
```

ActionScript:

```
function showBookmarkDialog() : void
{
    ExternalInterface.registerCallback(
        "onBookmarkDialogClosed", 
        onBookmarkDialogClosed
    );
    ExternalInterface.call(
        "FB.Connect.showBookmarkDialog", 
        /* ref to JS function onBookmarkDialogClosed ? */
    );
}

function onBookmarkDialogClosed(success:Boolean) : void
{
    // sweet, we made it back
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function onBookmarkDialogClosed()
{
    var success;
    // determine value of success
    getSWF().onBookmarkDialogClosed(success);
}
```

**Failed Experiments**
I have tried...

```
ExternalInterface.call(
    "FB.Connect.showBookmarkDialog", 
    "onBookmarkDialogClosed"
);

ExternalInterface.call(
    "FB.Connect.showBookmarkDialog", 
    onBookmarkDialogClosed
);

ExternalInterface.call(
    "FB.Connect.showBookmarkDialog",
    function() : void
    {
        ExternalInterface.call("onBookmarkDialogClosed");
    }
);

ExternalInterface.call(
    "FB.Connect.showBookmarkDialog",
    function()
    {
        this["onBookmarkDialogClosed"]();
    }
);
```

**Of note:**

1. Passing a string as the argument to an ExternalInterface call results in FB's JS basically trying to do `"onBookmarkDialogClosed"()` which, needless to say, will not work.
2. Passing a function as the argument results in a function object on the other side (confirmable with `typeof`), but it seems to be an empty function; namely, `function Function() {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, one need only ask a question for the answer to be revealed...

**Solution**

```
ExternalInterface.call("FB.Connect.showBookmarkDialog(onBookmarkDialogClosed)");
```